# First time i am deploying the code in server database is not connecting to my application

Tags: sql-server

iam using mvc3 application and sql server2008  in local it is working perfectly when i deploy in server data is not saving database

Comment: You really need to be a lot more specific... How are you connecting to the server? What language are you using? Any framework? Did the code ever work? Without knowing this there is no way that you can get a meaningful answer.

Comment: your question is quite broad... is there a database on your server? have you updated your connection strings to point to the database?

Comment: Did you check the connnection string is connecting to the  server DB.??

Comment: Have you provided a connection string and then open/closed the connection to the SQL Server: i.e

string connstr = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestImage; 
Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa";  
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr); 
conn.Open();
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have written it seems you are having trouble accessing the SQL Server from an application hosted on a seperate server ?

If this is the case theres a few things you can do:

1) Try pinging the SQl Server from your ApplicationServer to ensure
              you have network connectivity

2) On your SQL Server ensure you have remote connections enabled
              (Enable the TCP/IP service)

3) If you are using a SQL Login ensure your SQL Instance allows both
              windows authentication and SQL Logins.

4)Finaly logon to the actual SQL Server instance on the same server
   using SQL management studio with the same credentials you have in
   your connection string.